# Truffle compile command stuck at "Compiling your contracts..."

Tags: truffle

I developed a dapp using my PC (OS: Pop_OS!) and it was running fine. Then I had to format PC and installed new OS (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS), due to some issues in compatibility and performance.After that, I cloned the project from git and installed all dependencies using yarn and tried to compile the contracts. I was using truffle framework 5.0.7 and solidity ^0.5.0. I have done this few times in previous OS, it works fine. But, this time, when I tried to compile the contracts using "truffle compile" command, it stuck at "Compiling your contracts..." and simply exits after some time showing no error. Truffle simply not compiling the contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Truffle 0.5 downloads `solc` when you execute the compile command.  I'm not sure, but maybe Truffle hangs trying to download that.  Is it possible there is a firewall or similar preventing Truffle from hitting the network?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it happened to me too with fresh truffle install, thought I had hard time replicating the issue since after. Try following:

1. Check build folder and subfolder permission/owner or try deleting
   altogether
2. Check contracts folder permission/owner
3. Not ideal but
   running "sudo truffle migrate" would give an idea about source of
   issue, thought deleting the build folder and compiling again solved
   for me

Answer (score -1):

same problem for me, just run command with sudo and it will work

Comment: If sudo solve your problems it might be that some of your files have the wrong permissions/ownership. It is better to fix your issues than to rely on sudo regularly.